# Laravel type error: Argument 1 passed to lluminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager::createTokenRepository() must be

Tags: php, laravel

I have two types of users, normal and admins.

So i need create other controllers, brokers, etc to make the functionality works correctly.

When i click on "send password reset link" i get this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to 
Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager::createTokenRepository() 
must be of the type array, string given, called in 
/home/vagrant/Code/Manifiesto2017/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php on line 71
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Yes, a very easily understood error mesage I would say. So what is your question?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question fixed, don't pretend to be rude, but when you post an error you want fix it..

Comment: wow.. Thanks, know in which file? I'm confused, really.

Comment: Hi, try the given solution at the bottom [Here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1124)

Comment: I have the same, not working..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

This can happen when you don't set your app key.

you can set your app key by running `php artisan key:generate`

or you can hard code it in `config/app.php` set the app key you are good to go.

delete cache `/bootstrap/cache`.

then you are good to go.

I hope this helps

Comment: I have the key, so it's not the fault!, Thanks anyway